# Computing $H(Z|B)$ in a bipartite density matrix $\rho_{AB}$

Tags: measurement, entropy

Let's say Bob prepares a bipartite quantum state $\rho_{AB}$ to be shared between him and Alice. Bob sends Alice's part to her lab. Alice measures her subsystem $A$ in the computational basis $\mathcal{Z}$. Now we want to know the uncertainty in Alice's system given Bob's quantum memory register($B$). This quantity is denoted as $H(Z|B)$.

I was reading this [paper](http://www.iap.tu-darmstadt.de/tqp/papers/BerChrCol10.pdf) by Berta et al. where they mention in a footnote (page 2, footnote 4) that $H(R|B)$ is the conditional von Neumann entropy of the following state:
$$
  \left(\sum_j |\psi_j \rangle \langle\psi_j| \otimes \mathbb{1} \right) \rho_{AB} \left(\sum_j |\psi_j \rangle \langle\psi_j| \otimes \mathbb{1} \right),
$$
where $|\psi_j \rangle$ is the eigenvector of the measurement $\mathcal{R}$. In our case, this would be $\mathcal{Z}$.

My confusion now is this. We know that the sum of eigenvectors of the computational basis $\mathcal{Z}$ makes up the identity matrix $\mathbb{1}$ again. In this case, isn't it becoming the following?

$$
  \left(\mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1} \right) \rho_{AB} \left( \mathbb{1} \otimes \mathbb{1} \right) = \rho_{AB},
$$
in which case the conditional von Neumann entropy is simply $H(A|B)$. In the end, are we getting $H(Z|B) = H(A|B)$? This does not seem correct though. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was it still there by the time it was published?  [Nature link](https://www.nature.com/nphys/articles) to abstract, and [ArXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.0950) to newer version.

Comment: I see, that must be it. Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost certainly meant to be the post measurement state
$$
\sum_j \left(|\psi_j\rangle \langle \psi_j| \otimes \mathbb{1}\right) \rho_{AB} \left(|\psi_j\rangle \langle \psi_j| \otimes \mathbb{1}\right).
$$
Alternatively you may see such a state written as
$$
\sum_{j} |j \rangle \langle j |  \otimes \rho_B(j) 
$$
where $\rho_B(j) = \mathrm{tr}_B[ |\psi_j\rangle \langle \psi_j |  \rho_{AB}]$.